# Can specializations of a template function be virtual?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Something like, for example,

```
class A {
    template<typename T> T DoStuff();
    template<> virtual int DoStuff<int>() = 0;
};
```

Visual Studio 2010 says no, but I get a funny feeling that I simply messed up the syntax. Can explicit full specializations of a member function template be virtual?

Comment: You should still get an error even if you drop the `virtual`, right?

Comment: Even if it was legal. Why would you make the maintainers life harder by writing that. Remember he owns an Axe.

Comment: @Tux-D: Because, whilst I could create DoStuffInt functions for about five or more different types, it's not really the ideal solution, and secondly, because the Windows headers have a billion macro leakage problems that this would avoid, whereas some of my normal function names would have a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Explicit specializations aren't legal within a class. Even if you could make it a partial specialization you would still run into the "templates can't be virtual" problem.

n3290, § 14.5.2 states:

> A member function template shall not be virtual.

And gives this example:

```
template <class T> struct AA {
  template <class C> virtual void g(C); // error
  virtual void f(); // OK
};
```

Before going on to state that member function templates do not count for virtual overrides too.

Comment: You cannot partially specialize a function template. http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Comment: @n.m - true, that was more of a hypothetical "even if". I'll clear it up in the text though.

Answer (score 2):

According to C++98 Standard member function template shall not be virtual. http://www.kuzbass.ru:8086/docs/isocpp/template.html.

> -3- A member function template shall not be virtual. [Example:
>
> ```
> template <class T> struct AA {
>   template <class C> virtual void g(C);   //  error
>   virtual void f();                       //  OK
> };
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a similar effect by overloading your function template with a regular non-template virtual function.